# Writing a paper about a conceptual idea, that might not be possible, basically theoretical fiction

Tags: publications

Curious if there are certain outlets to distribute a paper pertaining to conceptual ideals regarding future technological topics and or method advancements in physics or computer programming, science. I understand how science is provable and routed in a nonfictional foundation, but sometimes imagination is a great outlet. I understand a simple answer would be publishing a fiction novel, but it seems somewhere in my lifetime I have read or learned about how many incredibly smart people ponder ideas that are inconceivable to be proven mathematically, and publish a paper somewhere. This is in the hope that maybe it sparks a future interest and research to actually prove if something is possible.

What is this correctly referred to as in regards to the topic of science, if it is even legitimate? And how is the proper way to maybe title a paper such as this without coming across as completely academic and accurate? I know this may prompt an answer stating that it all depends on how you explain what you are describing in your paper, but it is more about if this type of paper is allowed and accepted to certain outlets.

Maybe a great example would be writing a paper about if this world we live in is a simulation.

Comment: Papers *have* been published about the simulation hypothesis. I think much of what you're talking about falls under the discipline of futurology. See, e.g. https://www.nickbostrom.com/

Comment: @Max Where would you submit a paper such as the ones you mentioned to? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Take a look at Nick Bostrom's CV and see where he has published.